# How to make this explosion look less orthogonal?

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation, fire

Suggestions on how to make this look more natural without increasing the resolution too greatly? Trying to minimize bake time.

[image]

https://youtu.be/gKrwqdeRbuY

[image]

Comment: How exactly is the explosion being generated? Too strong of an outward force can make even a high resolution simulation behave strangely.

Comment: you took a resolution of 45...increase it ...and it should look better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't think that this is possible without increasing the resolution because this is exactly what resolution if for. It "increases" the "details".

So here is the result for resolution 110:

[image]

I know it's hard to accept and if someone shows me there is another way, i am happy too. But simulations are very time/render time/computational time consuming because there happens a lot of "stuff" and calculations in the "background".